# PHP Tidy: tidy_setopt() alternative?

Tags: php, set, tidy

So I'm trying to tailor PHP's Tidy to my liking, but the problem is with the `tidy_setopt()` function.

I *know* tidy is installed and working just fine, and reading the PHP docs it says `tidy_setopt()` has been removed as of 2.0 (So since the ob callback is working perfectly I'm safe to assume I'm running Tidy 2.0+).

Here is the problem: There is no alternative function. I'm hoping there is a way to get around this so I can set the ob handler's settings up how I want them to without actually needing to edit a configuration file.

I'm sure my hosting will be willing to edit Tidy's configuration file if needed, but I'd rather not add to the barrage of support tickets I've been sending them for various reasons as it is.

If I need to create my own callback for output buffering I can do so (I see some possibly useful methods using the OO approach to tidy) but I'd rather have it as slim as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
tidy_setopt('indent', FALSE);
```

You should use

```
$config = array('indent' => FALSE);
$text = tidy_parse_string($text, $config, 'UTF8');
```

Also see [Output Control Functions manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) for "User defined callback function example"